# Creating menu with sub menus from two arrays in PHP

Tags: php

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Tops
                [parent_id] => 
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Trousers
                [parent_id] => 
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => Dresses
                [parent_id] => 
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 4
                [name] => Skirts
                [parent_id] => 
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 5
                [name] => Accessories
                [parent_id] => 
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 6
                [name] => Coats & Jackets
                [parent_id] => 
            )

)
```

Above is the parent categories i fetch from db.

And below are the sub categories

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => Mini Tops
            [parent_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => Long Tops
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [name] => Cargo
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => Bermuda
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Formal Dresses
            [parent_id] => 3
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Casual Dresses
            [parent_id] => 3
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 14
            [name] => Party Wear
            [parent_id] => 3
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [name] => Jewelry 
            [parent_id] => 4
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 16
            [name] => Bracelets
            [parent_id] => 4
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 17
            [name] => Caps
            [parent_id] => 4
        )

)
```

below is how i am making my navitaion bar

```
             <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="search.html">Tops</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="search.html">Tshirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="search.html">Jumpers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="search.html">Cardigans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="search.html">Knitwear</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

As my logics are not so much good i actually trying to make navitaion with these two arrays in a way that the first array which are main links should be on top order where as all respective childs will appear in submenu of there respective parent_id example

Long Top, Cargo and Bermuda should be falling under Trousers Link.

I need guidance how can i achieve this .. I tried foreach loop but stucked in middle

Thanks alot

Comment: I'm unsure what 'stucked in middle' means, can you clarify?

Comment: i used for lop for parent categories and a nested for loop for child now i am confuse what should i do.. Infact i am not sure how should i structure my array so that when on view page (codeigniter) i can make menu with submenus from a single array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in control you should try to use a different choice of arrays because now you will be doing an unnecessary amount of looping. To demonstrate:

```
foreach($categories as $cat) {
    echo "<li>".$cat->name."<ul>";
    foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
        if($subcat->parent_id == $cat->id) echo "<li>".$subcat->name."</li>"
    }
    echo "</ul></li>";
}
```

You have to loop over all subcategories for each category. But if you instead stored subcategories in an array where the index represented the parent ID, you could easily retrieve them.

If you want to solve this with just one array you could make the list of subcategories a property of the corresponding parent category. This would be easy to handle and semantic.

Comment: I don't understand, so you can reference arrays as classes? I'm confused!

Comment: @Charles It was just a typo, fixed it.

Comment: This is something i was needing but the problem is that this thing is in my controller file i cannot directly echo from here... should i pass two arrays in view ? but then in my view i can use $subcat->parent_id ? 
P

Comment: I am compelled to pas one array only to the view ... and in that case your above code won't work

Comment: @user3445065 Yes, you can pass two arrays to the view. But like I said it would be better to find another solution. See the last paragraph for example. I'm not trying to write your code for you. I'm just using code explain the problem, and I also wrote that code because you said you had not been able to.

Comment: @Pickett thanks i passed two arrays and tried your code. Thanks